# PostgreSQL User Defined table type in memory

Tags: postgresql, in-memory-tables

If got several stored procedures (functions in PG) that need to pass around an intermediate result set between them (1K rows at most)

I can do this in other DBMS's but would like to know how to accomplish this in native PostgreSQL.

Specifically does PG support:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE(...)
```

Also can we do this completely in memory?

I want to pass a "MyTable" between several procs as input and output.

Or possibly could I build this result set and pass it around as a JSONB parameter?

I need this to be blazingly fast, no matter how it's done.

Comment: Would using jsonb for passing around the result set be fast?  Could I index it somehow? I"m worried about it begin slow.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but the best way is probably to pass a cursor between the functions.

Here is a toy example, see [the documenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) for more:

```
CREATE FUNCTION a() RETURNS refcursor
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   c refcursor := 'cursorname';
BEGIN
   OPEN c FOR SELECT 42 AS col1;
   RETURN c;
END;$$;

CREATE FUNCTION b() RETURNS SETOF integer
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   c refcursor;
   r record;
BEGIN
   c := a();

   LOOP
      FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO r;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      RETURN NEXT r.col1;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

That example works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM b();

 b  
----
 42
(1 row)
```

Comment: I don't believe a ref cursor will work.  It's more like a set of data I need to pass around and manipulate as it goes down the line of procs.

Comment: Then you cannot avoid passing the data around directly, e.g. in a `jsonb`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array of the table's type around:

```
create function function_one()
  returns void
$$
declare
  l_rows my_table[];
begin
  select array_agg(mt)
    into l_rows
  from my_table mt
  where ...;

  perform function_two(l_rows);
  perform function_three(l_rows);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Could you expand on what "my_table" actually is?  How do I declare the "tables type"?  Also could you show me the definition of function_two?

Comment: @MikeMoening: well it's the table which you want to load into memory.

Comment: Wow.  So it automatically builds an array with the same columns that exist in the table?  If so can I define a user defined table type (not a real one) ?  Last question.  How do you define the incoming table in function_two() ?